# invalid operation when opening a record set

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

I am having a problem opening a recordset against a table that is linked from SQLServer. I am running the following VBA and receiving an "invalid operation" error.
Thanks for the help.

```vb
Private Sub Add_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Add_Click
Dim myRS As DAO.Recordset
Dim myDB As DAO.Database
Dim myI As Variant, myPO As Variant, myJ As Variant
Dim myWS As Workspace

    Set myWS = DBEngine(0)
     
    Set myDB = CurrentDb
   
    Set myRS = myDB.OpenRecordset("PO_Numbers_tbl", dbOpenTable)
    
    myI = Me![End] - Me![Start] + 1

    myPO = Me![Start]
    For myJ = 1 To myI
        myRS.AddNew
        myRS![PO_Number] = myPO
        myRS.Update
        myPO = myPO + 1
    Next myJ
    
    myRS.Close
    myDB.Close
    Me.Requery
    
Exit_Add_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Add_Click:
    MsgBox Err.DESCRIPTION
    Resume Exit_Add_Click
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line triggers error? Step debug code and/or disable error handler for debugging.

Comment: Is this VBA in Access? Really no SQL involved since you are just referencing table.

Comment: Access is frontend and SQLServer is backend?

Comment: Why declare and set workspace object and then not use it?

Comment: And why declare `myJ`, `myI` and `myPO` as variants? These should be numeric, probably long.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `dbOpenTable` as the Recordset type, which is only valid for native Access tables. When using SQL Server tables, try using `dbOpenDynaset`.

I prefer to leave my linked SQL server tables named "dbo_" so that I know when they are not an Access table.

Regards,